# How to parse root elements from XSD

Tags: java, xml, parsing, xsd, schema

I have a problem with XSD parsing.

how can I parse root elements from XSD with Java?

Here is an example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns="http://beep2000/client/beep.de" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://beep2000/client/beep.de">
```

....

```
<xsd:complexType name="RequestEnvelope">
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="Title" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                    <xsd:element name="Forename" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                    <xsd:element name="Surname" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1"/>
                    <xsd:element name="PersonalID" minOccurs="0">
                        <xsd:simpleType>
                            <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                                <xsd:maxLength value="20"/>
                            </xsd:restriction>
                        </xsd:simpleType>
                    </xsd:element>
                    <xsd:element name="Adress" type="AdressType" minOccurs="0"/>
                    <xsd:element name="Body" type="BodyType" minOccurs="0"/>
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:complexType name="ResponseEnvelope">
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="Result" minOccurs="1">
                        <xsd:simpleType>
                            <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                                <xsd:maxLength value="3"/>
                                <xsd:enumeration value="OK"/>
                                <xsd:enumeration value="NOK"/>
                            </xsd:restriction>
                        </xsd:simpleType>
                    </xsd:element>
                    <xsd:element name="Errorcode" type="xsd:integer" minOccurs="0"/>
                    <xsd:element name="Errortext" minOccurs="0">
                        <xsd:simpleType>
                            <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                                <xsd:maxLength value="255"/>
                            </xsd:restriction>
                        </xsd:simpleType>
                    </xsd:element>
                    <xsd:element name="Comment" type="TextType" minOccurs="0"/>
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:element name="MsgResponse" type="ResponseEnvelope"/>
            <xsd:element name="MsgRequest" type="RequestEnvelope"/>
   </xsd:schema>
```

I want to parse "MsgRequest" and "MsgResponse".

How can I solve this?

Kind regards

Thank you!

Comment: Download the xsd.exe too from msdn. The convert the xsd scema to classes using xsd.exe.  From cmd.exe use following (/c is classes and /l is language c#) >.\xsd.exe /c /l:cs filename.xsd.  The use Xml Serialization to parse the file.

Comment: @jdweng I think they wanted a Java solution.

Comment: `xjc` would be the equivalent Java tool to my understanding.  (part of `jaxb`.)